# FreeMarker header and Page Breaks

Tags: java, freemarker

I am using Free Marker API for text report, I have an requirement to prepare reports, with page breaks.  Any Sample Needed.  Sample Report header as Follows, how to achieve page 1 of 2.

GP2602P                           REPORT RUN DATE :           08/16/2012 04:50:13  Page 1 of 3 
GPP GTB DASHBOARD         REPORT DATE    : 08/16/2012 04:50:13

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How are you determining what fits on a page?